# Combining 3 comma separated data and insert it to mysql using php

Tags: php

I have 3 comma separated strings. Each have the same number of entries:

```
$a = "1,2,3,4,5";
$b = "a,b,c,d,e,f";
$c = "f1,f2,f3,f4,f5";
```

I need to match the corresponding from each array together, to create groups of three entries:

```
1, a, f1
2, b, f2
3, c, f3
etc.
```

and inserted this into a table.

```
$match_string_to_insert = "
insert into table 
    (alpha,num,ran) 
values
    ('$a0','$b0','$c0'), 
    ('$a1','$b1','$c1'), 
    ('$a2','$b2','$c2'), 
    ('$a3','$b3','$c3'), 
    ('$a4','$b4','$c4')"
```

I already use `array_combine()`, but all the data is not inserted.

Comment: OK I think I see what you mean now. Your `f1 - 2` was throwing me off. I thought that was an arithmetic operation.

Comment: lol its ok, someone has edited it,
the actual data is = 
(1, a, f1),
(2, b, f2),
(3, c, f3),
(4, d, f4),
(5, e, f5);

Comment: What mysql API are you using? Mysqli or PDO?

Comment: thank for asking, i use Mysqli

Comment: Make sure you're using prepared statements and binding the parameters to that prepared statement. Never put variables directly into the query as you have it.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, I will do my best :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you do not have very much data and number of items are equal in all of the three**

```
$num = '1,2,3,4,5,6';
$alpha = 'a,b,c,d,e,f';
$random = 'f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6';


$num = explode( ',', $num );
$alpha = explode( ',', $alpha );
$random = explode( ',', $random );


$item_count = count( $num );

for($i=0; $i < $item_count; $i++)

    mysqli_query($mysql_conn, "INSERT INTO table SET num = {$num[$i]}, alpha = '{$alpha[$i]}', random = '{$random[$i]}'");
```

Comment: work like charm!!, thank for helping me, now i can sleep.